# Register Twilio SIM via API

Tags: mobile, sms, twilio, iot, sim-card

I have an unregistered Twilio SIM. I know I can go [here](https://www.twilio.com/console/wireless/sims/register) to register it, but is there any way I can do this programatically via the API?

[These](https://www.twilio.com/docs/wireless/api/sim) are the docs I found on the SIM API and it doesn't make any mention of being able to do the actual registration via the API.

Please tell me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio SIMs that come as part of the multipack require registering with your account in the console, as you've pointed out. These SIMs are development SIMs thus may be shared around, and can be registered with the number above the barcode. There is no API for this, just the form in the console.

If you have moved beyond experimenting and developing with the SIMs and you need a lot of them then you can bulk order the multi size SIMs from your console and they will come pre-registered to your account. These SIMs can't be shared with other developers, but are ready to be deployed into production for your account.

Does that help at all?